# can't pickle module objects with multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multiprocessing, pickle

Love the community on Stackedoverflow and have a problem i am unable to solve with multiprocessing. I will do my best to explain it in detail and greatly appreciate any guidance you gurus out there can provide. I have spent many hour looking at other posts with no luck.

My work involves very little python coding (0.1%) and i pretty much do it as a hobby or to reformat ascii data for later processing in software packages. I recently received a hand grenade of 50+ GB of data to process and need to take advantage of multiprocessing to reduce processing times. I have the code working on a single processor (with a for in range loop) but it took 4 days to process something i need to do on a much larger dataset (multiple times).

Main code is (Credits to Tom Irvine who is the developer of Vibrationdata, i have modified alot of his code in these works).

```py
from __future__ import print_function

import process_image
import calculate
import sys
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from vb_utilities import read_two_columns_from_dialog
from multiprocessing import Pool

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    print ("Python 2.x")
    import Tkinter as tk
    from tkFileDialog import asksaveasfilename
    import tkMessageBox
           
if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    print ("Python 3.x")    
    import tkinter as tk 
    from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename       
    import tkinter.messagebox as tkMessageBox


os.chdir('C:/Users/me?/Desktop/Data Processing All/Data processing/psd')
cps = np.loadtxt('CP1m.csv',delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
lcps=len(cps)
temp=np.zeros((1,3),dtype=float)

filenamestart='psdx'
data_filenames = [filename for filename in os.listdir('C:/Users/me?/Desktop/Data Processing All/
      Data processing/psd') if filename.startswith(filenamestart) and filename.endswith("01.npy")]
ndata_filenames=len(data_filenames)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(process_image, data_filenames)
```

Problem number 1:
Receive 'TypeError: can't pickle module objects' error when passing data_filenames to pool. 'data_filenames' is a list of locations and the data number set from that location (ie 'psdx10348_1001.npy' ignore the first 1s is location 348 and dataset 1). Tried data_filenames as a list and as a numpy array (5500,1). Fails, even if i change the 'process_image' function to simply print a word. Currently i have hit the wall here but i will post the functions envoked because these use 'np.load(?, allow_pickle=True' to load hundreds of thousands of files in the process and i will probably get further error messages from these files.

```
calculate.py
def calculate(a,b):
    iex  =2   # excitation type
    iresp=1   # response type
    irat =2   # amplitude type
    
    
    if(iresp==1):
    ##      disp('  1= acceleration ')
    ##      disp('  2= acceleration^2 ')
        if(irat==1):
            tlabel='Acceleration'
    #    
            if(iex==1):
                MFRF=lambda omega, rho, damp: (np.sqrt((1+(2*damp*rho)**2)/((1-rho**2)**2+(2*damp*rho)**2)))      
            else:
                MFRF=lambda omega, rho, damp: (np.sqrt(omega**2/((1-rho**2)**2+(2*damp*rho)**2)))             
    
        else:
            tlabel='Acceleration^2'
    #    
            if(iex==1):
                print(" * ref 1 * ")
                MFRF=lambda omega, rho, damp: ((1.+(2.*damp*rho)**2)/((1.-rho**2)**2+(2.*damp*rho)**2))        
            else:
                MFRF=lambda omega, rho, damp: ((omega**2/((1-rho**2)**2+(2*damp*rho)**2)))          
    
    #
    if(iresp==2):
    ##      disp('  1= velocity ')
    ##      disp('  2= velocity**2 ')
      
        if(irat==1):
            tlabel='Velocity'
    #    
            if(iex==1):
                MFRF=lambda omega, rho, damp: (np.sqrt(((1+(2*damp*rho)**2)/omega)/((1-rho**2)**2+(2*damp*rho)**2)))       
            else:
                MFRF=lambda omega, rho, damp: (np.sqrt(omega/((1-rho**2)**2+(2*damp*rho)**2)))              
    #      
        else:
            tlabel='Velocity^2'
    #    
            if(iex==1):
                MFRF=lambda omega, rho, damp: (((1+(2*damp*rho)**2)/omega)/((1-rho**2)**2+(2*damp*rho)**2))       
            else:
                MFRF=lambda omega, rho, damp: ((omega/((1-rho**2)**2+(2*damp*rho)**2)))          
      
    #
    if(iresp==3):
    ##      disp('  1= displacement ')
    ##      disp('  2= displacement**2 ')
      
        if(irat==1):
            tlabel='Displacement'
    #    
            if(iex==1):
                MFRF=lambda omega, rho, damp: (np.sqrt(((1+(2*damp*rho)**2)/omega**2)/((1-rho**2)**2+(2*damp*rho)**2)))        
            else:
                MFRF=lambda omega, rho, damp: (np.sqrt(1/((1-rho**2)**2+(2*damp*rho)**2)))            
    #      
        else:
            tlabel='Displacement^2'
    #    
            if(iex==1):
                MFRF=lambda omega, rho, damp: (((1+(2*damp*rho)**2)/omega**2)/((1-rho**2)**2+(2*damp*rho)**2))        
            else:
                MFRF=lambda omega, rho, damp: ((1/((1-rho**2)**2+(2*damp*rho)**2)))      
    '''print('pass')'''
     
    
    nt=int(2500)        
    n=len(a)  
    
    
    fstart=float(0.1)
    '''tkMessageBox.showwarning("warning", "Enter start frequency",parent=self.button_calculate)       
        return '''           
       
              
    '''fend=float(a[n-1])'''   
    fend=200.0
    '''tkMessageBox.showwarning("warning", "Enter end frequency",parent=self.button_calculate)                    
        return'''
    
    
    '''if(fstart<min(a)):
        fstart=min(a[0])'''             
    
    for i in range(0,n):
        if(a[i]>=fstart):
            i1=i
            break
    
    for i in range(i1,n):
        if(a[i]>fend):
            i2=i
            break
        else:
            i2=62
    
    
    fr=np.zeros(i2,'f')
    ar=np.zeros(i2,'f')
    
    maxb=0
    
    for i in range(i1,i2):                  
        if(b[i]>maxb):
            maxb=b[i]
            maxa=a[i]
    
    
    maxf=maxa 
    
    tpi=2*np.pi        
    
    
    error_max=1.0e+90
    
    Ar=0
    fnr=0
    dampr=0        
    
    '''print(' ')
    print('  i     A     fn     damp ')  '''      
    
    
    for i in range(0,nt):
    
        if(i<5 or np.random.random()<0.6):
            A=(0.99+0.02*np.random.random())
            damp=0.5*np.random.random()**1.5
            fn=maxf*(0.995+0.01*np.random.random())
    
        else:
            if(np.random.random()<0.4):
                fn=fnr*(0.995+0.01*np.random.random())  
                damp=dampr*(0.99+0.02*np.random.random())       
                A=Ar*(0.995+0.01*np.random.random())
            else:
                if(np.random.random()<0.5):
                    fn=fnr*(0.995+0.01*np.random.random())
                else:
                    damp=dampr*(0.995+0.01*np.random.random())                  
        
    
        if(fn<fstart or fn>maxf):
            fn=maxf
    
        if(A<0.2 or A>5):
            A=maxb*(0.8+0.4*np.random.random())
    
        if(damp>0.5):
            damp=0.5*(np.random.random())**2        
    
        error=0
    
        omegan=tpi*fn
        
    
        c=np.zeros(i2,'f')
    
        for j in range(i1,i2):
            omega=tpi*a[j]
            rho=omega/omegan
            c[j]=MFRF(omega, rho, damp)
    
        AX=A*maxb/max(c)
        c=AX*c
    
        for j in range(i1,i2):
            bbb=abs(np.log10(b[j]/c[j]))
            error=error+bbb
    
        if(error<error_max):
    
            error_max=error
            dampr=damp
            fnr=fn
            Ar=A
            cr=c
    
            '''print(' %d  %7.3g  %7.3g  %7.3g' %(i,A,fn,damp))'''
    
            k=0
    
            for j in range(i1,i2):
                fr[k]=a[j]              
                ar[k]=cr[j]
                k=k+1
                        
                        
    '''print(dampr)'''
    
    Qr=1/(2*dampr)
            
    '''print('\n Results \n')
    print(' fn =%7.3g Hz \n damping ratio = %7.3g \n Q =%7.3g \n' %(fnr,dampr,Qr))'''
    return(fnr,dampr,Qr)
```

process_image.py

```
def process_image(name):
    print(name)
    filenamestart = name[0:9]
    data_filenames = [filename for filename in name if filename.startswith(filenamestart) and filename.endswith(".npy")]
    ndata_filenames=len(data_filenames)
    switch=0
    tempname='C:/Users/mranderson/Desktop/Data Processing All/Data processing/psd'
    if ndata_filenames > 0:
        for j in range(ndata_filenames):
            data=np.load(data_filenames[j], allow_pickle=True)
            if switch==0:
                (a, b, c) = calculate(data[:,0:1],data[:,1:2])
                hpcx=np.zeros((1,3),dtype=float)
                hpcx[0,0],hpcx[0,1],hpcx[0,2] = a, b, c
                switch=1
            else:
                (a, b, c) = calculate(data[:,0:1],data[:,1:2])
                temp[0,0],temp[0,1],temp[0,2] = a, b, c
                hpcx = np.append(hpcx, temp, axis=0)
        print('no')
        tempname=tempname[0:-4] + '/hpc/hpcx' + data_filenames[j][4:9] + '.npy'
        np.save(tempname, hpcx)
```

The result from the process should be a '.np' file saved with all the calculations for each location in rows from 1 to x from that location (ie 'psdx10348_1001.npy' to say 'psdx10348_1100.npy' in a single file named 'psdx10348'). Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am unsure if this is a simple syntax problem or more involved. Currently processing the data would take over a month to process on a single processor. Thanks in advance boffins of python.

Comment: change import `import process_image` to `from process_image import process_image` because `pool.map` needs a function not the whole library. Naming your function the same as your module can cause this confusion / typo. The specific error you're getting is that you can't "pickle" the entire library to be sent to the child process, but sending a function from the library should be fine (and is probably what you meant to do anyway).

Comment: Usually including the full error trace (stuff before the `TypeError: `...) is very helpful in letting us figure out what's going wrong. It also lets you know to some degree what code is being touched, and what you might need to include in your question. In this case you never get so far as executing anything from `process_image`, and you import `calculate`, but then never do anything with it. Shrinking down the problem to it's core components often can lead to you solving it on your own, or at least makes it quicker and easier for one of us to digest.

Comment: Thanks Aaron! you were spot on with 'from process_image import process_image'. The multiprocessing does now commence (cpu usage is upto 100% and i have ~90 python files executing). Unfortunately there are no files being written from the function...? Looks as though it maybe an issue with Spyder, looking into it.

Comment: I also use spyder as my ide, and I will say using the built-in ipython console can cause problems when using gui's or when `print`ing from child processes, but I have never had a problem from simply writing files to disk. That said, I frequently set the "Run" setting to "Execute in an external system terminal" for the best compatibility. I didn't comb through your other code to look for errors, so I don't immediately know what's wrong. I'd suggest starting with a pool of 1 worker (to simplify console output), and a bunch of `print` statements to see what's going on.

Comment: Hi Aaron. Once again you were spot on. Running "Execute in an external system terminal" has the code working as planned. Your assistance is greatly appreciated, thank you.